# Characterisation of projective modules over tensor products of fields

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, fields

Let $k$ be a field and $L_1$ and $L_2$ finite field extensions of $k$.
Let $A:=L_1 \otimes_k L_2$ as an algebra.

Question:

> Given a finitely generated $A$-module $M$, do we have that $M$ is projective if and only if $Ext_A^1(M,M)=0$?

Comment: $A$ is a product of local rings (fields if your extensions are separable), and a module decomposes into product of modules over each factor. For a local ring I believe the criterion is something like $Ext^1_A(M,k)=0$, where $k$ is the residue field.

Comment: @VictorPetrov Sure, $Ext_A^1(M,k)=0$ means that the module $\Omega^1(M)$ is zero and thus $M$ is projective. So $M$ projective iff $Ext_A^1(M,k)=0$ is trivial (assuming local) but I really look for $Ext_A^1(M,M)=0$ instead .As you noted, this question is only interesting for non-seperable extensions.